# How do I write Comparator.comparing

Tags: java, comparator

I have the following program

```
 List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("10", "68", "97", "9", "21", "12");

Collections.sort(numbers, (a, b) -> (b + a).compareTo(a + b));
```

Hi

How do I rewrite this code

> (b + a).compareTo(a + b)

to **Comparator.comparing**

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: What's the point of this comparator? `b+a` will always be equal to `a+b`, so `compareTo` would always return `0`, and it would have no effect on the order to the list.

Comment: Except we are comparing String, not int

Comment: Also state your expected output to figure out what is wrong

Comment: `(b+a)` will always be equal to `(a+b)` in all dimensions.

Comment: This comparator violates the transitivity requirement, as it considers the empty string equal to every other string while not every string is equal to any other.

Answer (score 1):

The **Comparator.comparing()** structure is meant to be used on Objects with multiple fields, so you can extract the desired field to be used as key.
This method accepts as parameter the **Function** used to extract the **Comparable sort key**.

However for sorting a List<String>, this is not needed.
Since there is only your String value and no other ambiguous fields that can be used as key.

If you want to sort this List on **(a+b).compareTo(b+a)**

```
List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("10", "68", "97", "9", "21", "12");
```

Then your code with a standard comparator:

```
numbers.sort((a, b) -> (a+b).compareTo(b+a));
```

and the code using Compartor.comparing:

```
numbers.sort(Comparator.comparing((String s) -> s, (a, b) -> (a+b).compareTo(b+a)));
```

will both output:

```
[ 10, 12, 21, 68, 97, 9 ]
```

But as you can see, on a List<String> this is unnecessary and ends up duplicating code.

---

if it is unclear, then here is an example of a proper use case of **Comparator.comparing**
Let's say we have this class

```
public class Car {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private int tires;

    public Car(String name, String type, int tires) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.tires= tires;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public int getTires() {
        return tires;
    }
}
```

And a list of cars

```
List<Car> carsList = new ArrayList<Car>();
carsList.add(new Car("Audi A3", "Hatchback", 4));
carsList.add(new Car("Tyrerell P34", "Formula One", 6));
carsList.add(new Car("1932 Morgan Aero 2-Seater Sports", "Sports", 3));
carsList.add(new Car("Avtoros Shaman", "All terrain", 8));
```

Then we can sort a List<Car> like this

```
// By the type
carsList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Car::getType));

// By the number of tires
carsList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Car::getTires));

// By the number of tires in reverse order
carsList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Car::getTires).reversed());                   

// First by the type and then by the number of tires in reverse order
carsList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Car::getType).thenComparing(Car::getTires).reversed());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing string to each other in order to get you list sorted.

If you are sorting using `a+b` then it means the result of the comparison will always give you the same result

use the following code

```
numbers.sort((a, b) -> a.compareTo(b));
```

Comment: String addition is not the same as integer addition, so `a + b != b + a`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the samples of 
Comparator.comparing is helpful when you have complex object and you want to order based on its properties.
In the following I have sorted String based on its length.

```
List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("10", "68", "97", "9", "21", "12");

Collections.sort(numbers, Comparator.naturalOrder()); //[10, 12, 21, 68, 9, 97]

Collections.sort(numbers, Comparator.reverseOrder()); //[97, 9, 68, 21, 12, 10]

numbers.sort(Comparator.comparing(String::length)); //[9, 97, 68, 21, 12, 10]

numbers.sort(Comparator.comparing(String::intern)); //[10, 12, 21, 68, 9, 97]

numbers.sort(Comparator.comparing((String num) -> num, (a, b) -> (b+a).compareTo(a+b)));// [9, 97, 68, 21, 12, 10]

    List<Movie> movies = Arrays.asList(
    new Movie("Lord of the rings"),
    new Movie("Back to the future"),
    new Movie("Carlito's way"),
    new Movie("Pulp fiction"));

    movies.sort(Comparator.comparing(Movie::getTitle));
```

Ref: https://reversecoding.net/java-8-comparator-how-to-sort-a-list/

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-